# FFmpeg streaming from local file too fast

Tags: ffmpeg, streaming, audio-streaming

I'm trying to stream from local file to icecast. When I'm running this command

```
ffmpeg -i .\rec_20190120-220001.opus -c:a libvorbis -b:a 500k -f ogg -content_type application/ogg icecast://source:test@localhost:8000/stream
```

ffmpeg encodes fastest as it can rather than 1x speed and it's too fast to streaming. How to limit encoding speed

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add `-re` to the input, which limits the reading speed of the input.

```
ffmpeg -re -i .\rec_20190120-220001.opus -c:a libvorbis ...
```